# Как добавить в массив значение

Tags: c, массивы

Как добавить в массив arr массив names3?

```
char* names[] = {"1", "Kandisz+Nora","B+","kdn@gm.com","3","2018.09.03"};
char* names2[] = { "2", "Kandisz+Nora","B+","kdn@gm.com","3","2018.09.03" };
char** arr[] = {names,names2};
    
char* names3[] = { "3", "Kandisz+Nora","B+","kdn@gm.com","3","2018.09.03" };
```

и как удалить из массива arr, например names2

Comment: Смотря что вы понимаете под "*удалить из массива*"...

Comment: Динамический массив, пытаюсь реализовать функцию добавление и удалений строк

Comment: `char** arr[] = {names,names2};` — массив статический, на 2 элемента.

Comment: А  как сделать динамическим?

Comment: мне надо сделать двумерный динамический массив из слов на СИ

Comment: на с++ я бы взял vector<string> и не парился бы

Comment: Возьмите массив `char** arr = malloc(n*sizeof(char*))`, ри необходимости изменяйте с помощью `realloc`...

Comment: можете пожалуйста написать как оно должно быть?

Comment: int num = 0;
 int N = 6;
 int M = 10;

 
 char** arr = malloc(M * sizeof(char*));
 
 

 char* names1[] = { "1", "Kandisz_Nora", "B+", "kdn@gm.com", "3", "2018.09.03." };
 char* names2[] = { "2", "Remek_Elek", "0-", "rek@ele.com", "2", "2015.02.18." };
 char* names3[] = { "3","Pop_Simon","B+","psm@vi.hu","3","2018.09.03." };
 
 //arr[] = { names1,names2,names3,names4,names5,names6,names7,names8,names9,names10 };
 arr[0][0] = names1[0];

Comment: как мне єто все правильно внести в массив?